# How to filter MySQL query to omit specific matches

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I do apologize for any description issues as this is my first post. I am attempting to write a query that will "return all salespersons who did NOT sell to company Red" for a specific set of tables. I will list the tables below (as well as my currently written query) but there is one salesperson who meets both criteria (sold AND not sold). I want to see how to omit them from the query results but am not finding a way.

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2tDq.png)

My query so far:

```
SELECT Salesperson.ID, Salesperson.Name
FROM Salesperson, Customer, Order
WHERE Salesperson.ID = Order.Sales_ID
AND Order.Cust_ID = Customer.ID
AND Order.Cust_ID <> (
                    SELECT Customer.ID
                    FROM Customer
                    WHERE Name = 'Red'
                    );
```

**The returned results:**

```
ID   Name
4    Pam
5    Alex
```

I am trying to make sure Pam does not return as you see she has two items in the Orders table, one with company Red and the other with company Yellow. I assume my query is returning her due to her order with company Yellow. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: you should use a join not a subquery

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What is your table structure?  That would help to see best way to build the query.

Comment: if this is your first post for not getting down voted you should provide all the information needed, though that expert can guess how is your database structure but its good to mention that.
By the way you have to use join for this purpose, learn it here :
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: This was the question given to me, so I again sorry for the lack of description. I assumed the primary keys for all tables was their ID column, but the foreign keys are as follows:

Orders.Cust_ID is the foreign key for Customer.ID
Orders.Sales_ID is the foreign key for Salesperson.ID

Comment: check the link, it is easy to understand

Comment: or not, w3schools has a terrible reputation (but it has got better). noting bets the actual manual:  https://www.mysql.com/

Answer (score 0):

First, learn how to use proper `join` syntax.  One method uses `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT s.ID, s.Name
FROM Salesperson s JOIN
     Orders o
     ON s.ID = o.Sales_ID JOIN
     Customer c
     ON o.Cust_ID = c.ID
GROUP BY s.ID, s.Name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN c.name = 'Red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Comment: I'll definitely investigate your query to learn, so I appreciate the feedback.